# How to make SWRevealViewController slide "over" the main view controller not "push" it out?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealController with swift and it is working how it is suppose to but I would like to tweak it a little.

When you bring out the menu, by either sliding or pressing the button, the new view comes out while pushing the main view controller to the side.

What I would like to have it do is slide over the main view controller so the main view controller stays where it is with the new view controller sliding over top of it.

Does that make sense? The only example I can think of is on the *Reddit News* app for Android. The slide out menu doesnt effect the main view controller it just slides out on top of it. (I know its different in Android)

Is this possible to do while using the SWRevealViewController class?

Comment: It is Android style.You want something like in Adobe Acrobat Reader app.I used SWRevealViewController in the past and I don't really think you can get what you want by using SWRevealViewController as it is.You have to change the way animations work and it is really deep

Comment: Ok, thats what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

what you're trying to do isn't the expected behavior of `SWRevealViewController` and thus it would require some low level coding for you to tweak an animation the way you're describing.

However i'd recommend using this pod instead https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu. It's an updated version and as you can see it provides several animations for you to choose from, the one you're looking for is *Slide in*. It's all really well documented.